# Populate select dropdown if returning with errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

As with my text fields, if an error is returned on the view, I want to populate the select elements with the previously submitted data, like: `value="{{ old('element_name_here') }}"`.

**Current view:**

```
<select class="form-control" id="input" name="{{ $questionDetail->question_number }}" required="required">
    <option disabled selected value> -- Select an option --</option>
        @foreach($answers as $answer)
            <option value="{{ $answer->value }}">{{ $answer->question }}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

How can I implement it into the above scenario, as there doesn't seem to be a place where I can add a value without overwriting one? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mark previous value as selected so something like this should work:

```
<select class="form-control" id="input" name="{{ $questionDetail->question_number }}" required="required">
    <option disabled @if(!old($questionDetail->question_number)) selected @endif value> -- Select an option --</option>
        @foreach($answers as $answer)
            <option value="{{ $answer->value }}" @if(old($questionDetail->question_number) == $answer->value) selected @endif>{{ $answer->question }}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

Probably when working a lot with forms it's a good idea to use https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html (branch 5.4)

Comment: Thank you. Instead of defaulting to the disabled option, it defaults to an answer from the dropdown, even though the form hasn't' been submitted, and so no errors have been returned?

Comment: @Ben Does any of options has empty value?

Comment: Yes, the top option was the empty disabled value. It's ok though, I've removed it and happy to have a default answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
<option 
    value="{{ $answer->value }}" 
    {{ $answer->value == old(questionDetail->question_number) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
        {{ $answer->question }}
</option>
```

You can remove 'selected' from the first option. It will be selected by default because it's the first. if `old()` exists, then it will do the check.